# Some terminology about CLI

Tags: terminology

Is there any difference in meaning between the following terms? Can they be used interchangeably?

- terminal
- console
- shell
- command line interface

If any, what are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

Typically in Linux we can see shell terminal and console as command line interfaces

A command line  interface is a communication mechanism in which we interact with the system via command or group of commands.

The difference between terminal, shell and console lies in which how they enable us to interact with the system. It is clearly explained at the following link:

[Difference between shell console and terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal).